# SDK Manager not opening in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I installed the `Android Studio` When I click on the SDK Manager or AVD Manager button in toolbar it cannot opens any thing . And when I open AVD or SDK Manager from the folder `C:\Program Files\Android\android-studio\sdk\tools\lib`  it gives the error that " Failed to execute tools/android.bat . the system cannot find the file specified".

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: create "add-ons" folder in "C:\Program Files\Android\android-studio\sdk"

Answer (score 2):

SDK Manager not launching from `Android Studio` because you have to start the `AndroidStudio` as `Run as administrator` privileges.

> Failed to execute tools/android.bat

Run the `android.bat` which is in tools directory of the sdk. Ex [C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\sdk\tools]

It will start the SDK Manager.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't sufficient because SDK Manager fails to update files because android.bat has control of the folder that needs to be update.  Basically it doesn't work correctly on Win8 because the files need to be in an Program Data folder instead of the Program Files folder.

Answer (score 1):

This is what i did to solve the problem;

1. went to https://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r24.0.2-windows.zip and downloaded that sdk tools
2. Extracted the file in one of the location of my choice
3. Copied the SDK Manager.exe from the extracted file
4. Went to the location where the original SDK Manager.exe was and replaced it with the one downloaded.
5. Went back to android studio and started SDK Manager, boom! SDK Manager launched perfectly

NOTE: I only replaced the SDK Manager.exe only. Hope this helps someone.